# how can I get 3 data in cycle with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I have a website which is using the CodeIgniter framework. In my one page I should get some data and list them. and I don't want to use the scrollbar on this page.

how can I get 3 data in cycle with jquery?

This code is getting just 1 data in cycle but I want to get 3 data in the cycle.

```
<ul class="list">
  <?php foreach ($a_list as $hd) { ?>
    <div id="content-1">
      <a href="single.html">
        <li>
          <section class="list-left" style="border:0px solid red; width:30%; height:90px;">
            <section class="list" style="border-bottom:1px solid red; width:100%; margin-top: 0; text-align: center">
              <h6 class="title" >Hasta</h6>
            </section>
            <p class="adprice" style="color:black; text-align: center; font-size: -5;"><?= $hd->h_adi ?> <?= $hd->h_soyadi ?>
          </section>
          <section class="list-left"style="border:0px solid red; width:30%; height: 90px"> 
            <section class="list" style="border-bottom:1px solid red; width:100%; margin-top: 0; text-align: center">
              <h5 class="title" >Doktor</h5>
            </section>
            <p class="adprice" style="text-align: center">
              <?= $hd->a_unvan ?>
              <?= $hd->dr_adi ?>
              <?= $hd->dr_sadi ?>
              <br>
              <p class=catpath style="text-align: center; margin-top: 0px !important; color:black">
                <?=$hd->a_brans?>
                Uzmanı
              </p>
            </p>
          </section>
          <section class="list-left" style="border:0px solid red; width:30%;height: 90px">
            <section class="list" style="border-bottom:1px solid red; width:100%; margin-top: 0; text-align: center">
              <h5 class="title" >Durum</h5>
            </section>
            <p class="adprice" style="color:blue;text-align: center"><?=$hd->h_durum?></p>
          </section>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </li> 
      </a>
    </div>
  <?php } ?>
  <script src='<?=base_url()?>/assets/js/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script>
    var divs = $('div[id^="content-"]').hide(),
    i = 0;
    (function cycle() { 
      divs.eq(i).fadeIn(400)
                .delay(1000)
                .fadeOut(400, cycle);
      i = ++i % divs.length;
    })();
  </script>
  <a href="single.html">
  </a>
</ul>
```

zxcf